# `gcloud images create <image> --source-uri=<source>` gives error in Cloud SDK 265.0.0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

Executions of `gcloud compute images create` that use the `--source-uri` flag are currently broken in release 265.0.0, returning an error stating:

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The Cloud Storage bucket 'storage' is not found.

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been identified by the Cloud SDK team and a fix will be included in release 266.0.0 on Tuesday, October 8th.

Public issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141954013

Workaround:

Images can be created using the Cloud Console, or the SDK version can be manually downgraded to Cloud SDK 264.0.0, using a command like:

`gcloud components update --version <VERSION>`

If you have installed via apt-get or yum, you may need to do the following:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=VERSION-0`

or

`sudo yum downgrade google-cloud-sdk-VERSION`